# VLC audio equalizer has no effect on recorded video

Tags: vlc-media-player, webcam

I'm trying to capture a video from Logitech c920 webcam and modify the audio that is recorded. I'm using the command

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=640:height=480 :input-slave='alsa://hw:1,0' --audio-filter equalizer --equalizer-bands "-20 -20 -20 -20 -20 -20 -20 -20 -20 -20" --no-equalizer-2pass --equalizer-preamp -2 --volume 10  --sout "#transcode{acodec=aac,ab=192}:file{dst=file.mp4}" -vvv --run-time 15 vlc://quit
```

It seems, that the --equalizer-bands and the --volume do not have any effect on the video recorded.